# Displaying Mysql Table in JList

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

trying to display a MySQL table in a jList, 
I wrote this code  the compiler doesn't show any error,so I can't figure out what's wrong

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    DefaultListModel dModel=(DefaultListModel)lst1.getModel();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root")) {
            String s="select * from song_list;";
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = (Statement)con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(s);
            while (rs.next()) //go through each row that your query returns
            {
                String ItemList2 = rs.getString("Song_Name"); //get the element in column "item_code"
                dModel.addElement(ItemList2); //add each item to the model
            }
            lst1.setModel(dModel);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code and a way to rectify it ? 
thank you for your help

Comment: thanks,and of course I'm removing it  :-p

Comment: Great, now the best thing you can do in this situation is debug. Only you have the full code and can test it. You will want to place println's strategically in your code to find out why it's not behaving as expected, either that or use a debugger. If this fails, then create and post a [mcve].